# Couchbase server and sync gateway not syncing

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

So I was doing a sample app that will have an offline functionality.

I have 2 buckets on my couch server hosted on my local machine, first is `restful-sample` and the other is `sync_gateway`. Now I already have written the api code for the backend and the CRUD is all working fine. For the `restful-sample` I have this `config.json` located on my project.

```
- app
     - models
     - node_modules
     - public
     - routes
     - app.js
     - config.json <-- this one
     ...
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "couchbase": {
        "server": "127.0.0.1:8091",
        "bucket": "restful-sample",
        "password": "123456"
    }
}
```

And then I also installed the `sync_gateway` on my machine and I also have this json config also located at the same project.

```
- app
     - models
     ...
     - config.json 
     - syncgw-config.json <-- this one
     ...
```

**syncgw-config.json**

```
{
    "interface": ":4987",
    "adminInterface": ":4988",
    "log": ["CRUD", "CRUD+", "HTTP", "HTTP+", "Access", "Cache", "Shadow", "Shadow+", "Changes", "Changes+"],
    "databases": {
        "cool_app": {
            "server": "http://localhost:8091",
            "bucket": "sync_gateway",
            "sync": `function(doc) {
                channel(doc.channels);

            }`,
            "users": {
                "GUEST": {
                    "disabled": false,
                    "admin_channels": ["*"]
                }
            },
            "shadow": {
                "server": "http://localhost:8091",
                "bucket": "restful-sample",
                "password": "cuaju_05"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first bucket `restful-sample` already has some data on it, stored via the API I created, written directly from the client side.

When I tried to run `./sync_gateway '/var/www/html/couchtest/syncgw-config.json'` the sync gateway is running smoothly on `http://localhost:4987/cool_app/` **BUT** the documents from the bucket `restful-sample` is not synced nor showing on the `sync_gateway` bucket on couchbase server running locally on my machine.

My question here is, am I doing it right? I am expecting to see the data from `restful-sample` to `snyc_gateway` bucket, am I expecting too much?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already reviewed the Sync Gateway logs?  With Shadow+ enabled you should get fairly detailed logging of the bucket shadowing processing.  The startup logging may also help to shed some light on what's going on.